# Even though I used BufferedReader to read a text, my code still gives timeout error

Tags: java

In a E Olymp task, I am required to convert each letter 'a' to 'b' and 'b' to 'a' including their uppercase and lowercase in the text. I have found a few ways but all of them gives timeout error. Even though I used BufferedReader which is fastest way to read a text, my code could not just pass more than 60 percent of test cases. Here are my codes, could you tell me what can cause timeout error?

First One:

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.BufferedWriter;
     import java.io.FileReader;
     import java.io.FileWriter;
     import java.io.IOException;
     public class Se{
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     try {
     BufferedReader aze = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
     BufferedWriter baze = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
      String u;
     String w = "";
     while((u=aze.readLine())!=null) {
        w += u + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    String a = w.replaceAll("a","1");
    String c = a.replaceAll("b","a");
    String d = c.replaceAll("1","b");
    String e = d.replaceAll("A","1");
    String f = e.replaceAll("B","A");
    String G = f.replaceAll("1","B");
    baze.write(G);
    baze.close();
        aze.close();
    }
    catch(Exception a) {
        
    }
    }
}
```

Second one:

```
     import java.io.*;
     public class Task{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     try {
     BufferedReader aze = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
     BufferedWriter baze = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
     String u;
     String w = "";
     while((u=aze.readLine())!=null) {
        w += u + System.lineSeparator();
     }
     String h = "";
     String a = "a";
     String b = "b";
     String A = "A";
    String B = "B";
    for(int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        String t = "" + w.charAt(i);
        if((t).equals(a)) {
            h += b;
        }
        else if(t.equals(b)) {
            h += a;
        }
        else if(t.equals(A)) {
            h += B;
        }
        else if(t.equals(B)) {
            h += A;
        }
        else {
            h += t;
        }
    }
    baze.write(h);
    baze.close();
        aze.close();
    }
    catch(Exception a) {
        
    }
    }
}
```

Third one:

```
  import java.io.*;
   public class Task{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    try {
    BufferedReader aze = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    BufferedWriter baze = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    String u;
    String w = "";
    while((u=aze.readLine())!=null) {
        w += u + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    String h = "";
    String a = "abAB";
    for(int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
            Character ch= w.charAt(i);
        if(ch.equals('a') || ch.equals('A')) {
            h += (char)((int)w.charAt(i)+1);
            j = a.length()-1;
        }
        else if(ch.equals('b') || ch.equals('B')) {
            h += (char)((int)w.charAt(i)-1);
            j = a.length()-1;
        }
        else {
        h += w.charAt(i);
        j = a.length()-1;
        }
    }
    }
    baze.write(h);
    baze.close();
        aze.close();
    }
    catch(Exception a) {
        
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `w += u + System.lineSeparator();`

This is incredibly inefficient. `StringBuilder` is how you'd efficiently concatenate strings, but in general these kinds of exercises should not involve concatenating in the first place. Read enough to do a job, then do it.

Same principle applies to `h`.

You are reading in **everything** (in a very inefficient manner), then looping through your input, writing your desired output to another string (again in a very inefficient manner), and then writing the whole thing out at once.

Instead, read as much as you need to generate some output, write that (immediately), and just keep going until you run out of input.

Answer (score 0):

You're overkilling the read, and `+=` operation on string as @rzwitserloot said, You should read, process and write at once and continue the process until the input file is empty.

However, you can do the whole mapping on the string you need using stream. I've changed your if-else bundle to a `translate` method using `switch` cases and mapped the characters of your input through it. Then finally wrote the mapped string into the output file and continued till the end of the input. Here's the full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader aze = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        BufferedWriter baze = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
        String u;
        while ((u = aze.readLine()) != null) {
            u = u.codePoints()
                    .parallel()
                    .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                    .map(Main::translate)
                    .collect(StringBuilder::new, (builder, c) -> 
                            builder.append((char) c), StringBuilder::append)
                    .toString();
            baze.write(u);
        }
        baze.close();
        aze.close();
    } catch (Exception a) {
        a.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static char translate(char x) {
    switch (x) {
        case 'A':
            return 'B';
        case 'B':
            return 'A';
        case 'a':
            return 'b';
        case 'b':
            return 'a';
        default:
            return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to cast code point to char.

Comment: @saka1029  what's the catch?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and arguably 'proper' way to do this is with a `FilterReader`. You can pass your 'input.txt' to it and it's easy enough to output to a file instead of stdout.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FilterReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

/**
 *
 * @author g00se
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class CharacterSubstitutionReader extends FilterReader {

    final String replacementCandidates;
    final String replacements;

    public CharacterSubstitutionReader(Reader in, final String replacementCandidates, final String replacements) {
        super(in);
        if (replacementCandidates.length() != replacements.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Replacement candidates string and replacements string must be equal in length");
        }
        this.replacementCandidates = replacementCandidates;
        this.replacements = replacements;
    }

    // For testing only
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Reader in = new CharacterSubstitutionReader(new FileReader(args[0]), "ab1AB1","1ab1AB");
        int numRead = -1;
        char[] buf = new char[1 << 10];
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) > -1) {
            System.out.print(new String(buf, 0, numRead));
        }

        in.close();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int c = super.read();
        int ix = replacementCandidates.indexOf(c);

        if (c < 0) {
            return c;
        } else if (ix >= 0) {
            c = replacements.charAt(ix);
        }

        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] b) throws IOException {
        return read(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] buf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (len <= 0) {
            if (len < 0) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            } else if ((off < 0) || (off > buf.length)) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }

            return 0;
        }

        int charsRead = 0;
        int c = read();

        while ((c > -1) && (charsRead < len)) {
            buf[off + charsRead++] = (char) c;
            c = read();
        }

        return (charsRead > 0) ? charsRead : (-1);
    }
}
```